# How do I make a single arm double tap a piano key?

Tags: ev3, programming, python, pybricks

I am trying to make a Lego play piano from ev3, where I have connected two arms to a single motor on either side using Lego elements. Both the arms move counterclockwise to one another (if one plays the key then another won't), the problem is that I need one of the arms to double tap on the key without the motor moving 360 degrees. How do I do it? I have used `run_time`, `run_target`, and `run_angle` but nothing seems to work.

[image: this is not the picture of my product but I assembled it by watching this video. Therefore, the assembly is similar]

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
from pybricks import ev3brick as brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import *
from pybricks.ev3devices import (Motor, TouchSensor, ColorSensor, InfraredSensor, UltrasonicSensor, GyroSensor)
from pybricks.parameters import Port
from pybricks.tools import wait

# Play a sound.
brick.sound.beep()

# Initialize a motor at port B.
test_motora=Motor(Port.A)
test_motorb = Motor(Port.B) 
test_motorc = Motor(Port.C)
test_motord=Motor(Port.D)

test_motord.run_target(500,-180)
test_motord.run_time(500,2000)
wait(1000)
test_motord.run_target(500,0)
test_motord.run_time(500,2000)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can already tap once. What is preventing you from repeating the same movement in order to tap twice?

Comment: Please [don 't upload code as a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557).

Comment: This is actually quite simple. Turn the motor enough degrees for it to touch the key, then use that same number of degrees to turn it back (but with a - before it to specify that it go backwards. After that, turn it that same number of degrees **again** but without the - this time.